# CPANEL - INSERT command denied, how to fix?

Tags: mysql, cpanel

has anybody encounter this error before?
Im using CPanel. SELECT Query is working fine.

```
INSERT command denied to user 'username'@'localhost' for table 'tablename'
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does the user have to correct user rights to perform `INSERT` statements to the database and/or table?

Comment: user might not have the privileges of insert command for the table. By using grant command you can access that privilege.

Comment: what is the complete command code? and where do i need to run that particular command? Is it in the phpmyadmin->SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user is setup on a MySQL database, different "privileges" are assigned. You can set up a user to only be permissible to select, only select, insert, update, etc.

It looks like the user you're connected as doesn't have sufficient privileges on the database to perform inserts.

It's not a good idea to assign too many privileges, as significant damage (drop table) could be done if your user's password was compromised.

Comment: -> Sir but there is no **"Priveleges"** tab in cpanel phpmyadmin. Any idea how can i figure it out?

Comment: There won't be a privileges tab in PHPMyAdmin. PHPMyAdmin is just a tool. It isn't MySQL. Look for something with "Users" written on it, you should see a list of users, and some way of setting their privileges. If you can't, try to add a new user and it should offer you the privileges options when creating the user.

Comment: Aha, just checked: Without being in a database, the "home" PHPMyAdmin panel has "Users" tab, in there, there's a list of users with *"Edit Privileges"* links on each.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `GRANTS` of this user:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for username@%                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*555D724CB4D1B463281FC9E27809C95A0CDE490E' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tablename`.* TO 'username'@'localhost'                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: sir where do i run this script? IDENTIFIED BY **PASSWORD** <-do i need to replace this with my dbpassword?

Comment: He is showing you how to run the mysql command from the command line. Since you are likely not using the command line, you can try running SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost'; in your sql client (phpmyadmin, heidisql, etc.), but it's likely your account won't have permissions to run that command either. You might want to check with the person who manages your cpanel account.